# Can I make this slider auto play?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I am trying to get this slider to auto play but I can't seem to get it to workDoes anyone know how I can achieve this?

This is the slideshow:

[Slideshow](https://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedFrameSlideshow/index6.html)

Comment: Have you tried `setTimeout` or `setInterval`?

Comment: This is the code that I have:

{
 function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  
  var timeout;
  return function() {
   var context = this, args = arguments;
   var later = function() {
    timeout = null;
    if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
   };
   var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
   clearTimeout(timeout);
   timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
   if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
   
  };

Comment: Look in the `class SlideShow` - There is a function`initEvents()` and right inside you have `this.navigate('next')` So just use `setInterval` and call `this.navigate('next')`

Comment: Please edit your answer and put the code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace demo6.js code with given -

```
{
    // From https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function.
    function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
        var timeout;
        return function() {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function() {
                timeout = null;
                if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
            if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
        };
    };

    class Slideshow {
        constructor(el, settings) {
            this.DOM = {};
            this.DOM.el = el;
            this.settings = {
                animation: {
                    slides: {
                        duration: 500,
                        easing: 'easeOutQuint'
                    },
                    shape: {
                        duration: 300,
                        easing: {in: 'easeOutQuint', out: 'easeOutQuad'}
                    }
                },
                frameFill: 'url(#gradient1)'
            }

            this.settings.autoSlide = settings.autoSlide || false;
            this.settings.autoSlideTimeout = settings.autoSlideTimeout || 4000;
            this.init();
        }
        init() {
            this.DOM.slides = Array.from(this.DOM.el.querySelectorAll('.slides--images > .slide'));
            this.slidesTotal = this.DOM.slides.length;
            this.DOM.nav = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.slidenav');
            this.DOM.titles = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.slides--titles');
            this.DOM.titlesSlides = Array.from(this.DOM.titles.querySelectorAll('.slide'));
            this.DOM.nextCtrl = this.DOM.nav.querySelector('.slidenav__item--next');
            this.DOM.prevCtrl = this.DOM.nav.querySelector('.slidenav__item--prev');
            this.current = 0;
            this.createFrame(); 
            this.initEvents();
        }
        createFrame() {
            this.rect = this.DOM.el.getBoundingClientRect();
            this.frameSize = this.rect.width/12;
            this.paths = {
                initial: this.calculatePath('initial'),
                final: this.calculatePath('final')
            };
            this.DOM.svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
            this.DOM.svg.setAttribute('class', 'shape');
            this.DOM.svg.setAttribute('width','100%');
            this.DOM.svg.setAttribute('height','100%');
            this.DOM.svg.setAttribute('viewbox',`0 0 ${this.rect.width} ${this.rect.height}`);
            this.DOM.svg.innerHTML = `
            <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#09012d"/>
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0f2b73"/>
            </linearGradient>
            </defs>
            <path fill="${this.settings.frameFill}" d="${this.paths.initial}"/>`;
            this.DOM.el.insertBefore(this.DOM.svg, this.DOM.titles);
            this.DOM.shape = this.DOM.svg.querySelector('path');
        }
        updateFrame() {
            this.paths.initial = this.calculatePath('initial');
            this.paths.final = this.calculatePath('final');
            this.DOM.svg.setAttribute('viewbox',`0 0 ${this.rect.width} ${this.rect.height}`);
            this.DOM.shape.setAttribute('d', this.isAnimating ? this.paths.final : this.paths.initial);
        }
        calculatePath(path = 'initial') {

            if ( path === 'initial' ) {
                return `M 0,0 0,${this.rect.height} ${this.rect.width},${this.rect.height} ${this.rect.width},0 0,0 Z M 0,0 ${this.rect.width},0 ${this.rect.width},${this.rect.height} 0,${this.rect.height} Z`;
            }
            else {
                const point1 = {x: this.rect.width/4-50, y: this.rect.height/4+50};
                const point2 = {x: this.rect.width/4+50, y: this.rect.height/4-50};
                const point3 = {x: this.rect.width-point2.x, y: this.rect.height-point2.y};
                const point4 = {x: this.rect.width-point1.x, y: this.rect.height-point1.y};

                return `M 0,0 0,${this.rect.height} ${this.rect.width},${this.rect.height} ${this.rect.width},0 0,0 Z M ${point1.x},${point1.y} ${point2.x},${point2.y} ${point4.x},${point4.y} ${point3.x},${point3.y} Z`;
            }
        }
        initEvents() {
            this.DOM.nextCtrl.addEventListener('click', () => this.navigate('next'));
            this.DOM.prevCtrl.addEventListener('click', () => this.navigate('prev'));

            window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(() => {
                this.rect = this.DOM.el.getBoundingClientRect();
                this.updateFrame();
            }, 20));

            document.addEventListener('keydown', (ev) => {
                const keyCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which;
                if ( keyCode === 37 ) {
                    this.navigate('prev');
                }
                else if ( keyCode === 39 ) {
                    this.navigate('next');
                }
            });

            if(this.settings.autoSlide) {
                setInterval(() => this.navigate('next'), this.settings.autoSlideTimeout);
            }
        }
        navigate(dir = 'next') {
            if ( this.isAnimating ) return false;
            this.isAnimating = true;

            const animateShapeIn = anime({
                targets: this.DOM.shape,
                duration: this.settings.animation.shape.duration,
                easing: this.settings.animation.shape.easing.in,
                d: this.paths.final
            });

            const animateSlides = () => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const currentSlide = this.DOM.slides[this.current];
                    anime({
                        targets: currentSlide,
                        duration: this.settings.animation.slides.duration,
                        easing: this.settings.animation.slides.easing,
                        translateY: dir === 'next' ? this.rect.height : -1*this.rect.height,
                        complete: () => {
                            currentSlide.classList.remove('slide--current');
                            resolve();
                        }
                    });

                    const currentTitleSlide = this.DOM.titlesSlides[this.current];
                    anime({
                        targets: currentTitleSlide.children,
                        duration: this.settings.animation.slides.duration,
                        easing: this.settings.animation.slides.easing,
                        delay: (t,i,total) => dir === 'next' ? i*100 : (total-i-1)*100,
                        translateY: [0, dir === 'next' ? 100 : -100],
                        opacity: [1,0],
                        complete: () => {
                            currentTitleSlide.classList.remove('slide--current');
                            resolve();
                        }
                    });

                    this.current = dir === 'next' ? 
                        this.current < this.slidesTotal-1 ? this.current + 1 : 0 :
                        this.current > 0 ? this.current - 1 : this.slidesTotal-1; 

                    const newSlide = this.DOM.slides[this.current];
                    newSlide.classList.add('slide--current');
                    anime({
                        targets: newSlide,
                        duration: this.settings.animation.slides.duration,
                        easing: this.settings.animation.slides.easing,
                        translateY: [dir === 'next' ? -1*this.rect.height : this.rect.height,0]
                    });

                    const newSlideImg = newSlide.querySelector('.slide__img');

                    anime.remove(newSlideImg);
                    anime({
                        targets: newSlideImg,
                        duration: this.settings.animation.slides.duration*3,
                        easing: this.settings.animation.slides.easing,
                        translateY: [dir === 'next' ? -100 : 100, 0],
                        scale: [0.2,1]
                    });

                    const newTitleSlide = this.DOM.titlesSlides[this.current];
                    newTitleSlide.classList.add('slide--current');
                    anime({
                        targets: newTitleSlide.children,
                        duration: this.settings.animation.slides.duration*1.5,
                        easing: this.settings.animation.slides.easing,
                        delay: (t,i,total) => dir === 'next' ? i*100+100 : (total-i-1)*100+100,
                        translateY: [dir === 'next' ? -100 : 100 ,0],
                        opacity: [0,1]
                    });
                });
            };

            const animateShapeOut = () => {
                anime({
                    targets: this.DOM.shape,
                    duration: this.settings.animation.shape.duration,
                    easing: this.settings.animation.shape.easing.out,
                    d: this.paths.initial,
                    complete: () => this.isAnimating = false
                });
            }

            animateShapeIn.finished.then(animateSlides).then(animateShapeOut);
        }
    };

    new Slideshow(document.querySelector('.slideshow'), {
        autoSlide: true,
        autoSlideTimeout: 4000 // 4 second
    });
    imagesLoaded('.slide__img', { background: true }, () => document.body.classList.remove('loading'));
};
```

I have added settings -

```
new Slideshow(document.querySelector('.slideshow'), {
    autoSlide: true,
    autoSlideTimeout: 4000 // 4 second
});
```

You may code diff to see the changes I have made.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! :))